# How to find the total output resistance for a mosfet cascadinging with a bjt?

Tags: mosfet, bjt, resistance

[image: Amplifier circuit]

I'm working on an problem in school. The original circuit was much bigger but I replaced the two current mirrors with DC current sources for simplicity. I know \$R_{in}\$ for the mosfet is infinite so the total \$R_{in}\$ for the amplifier is infinite. The mosfet acts as a voltage buffer. But I can't figure out how to get the total \$R_{out}\$ for the circuit.

*Info*. I already solved for: \$r_{o1}=8\mathrm{kohm}\$, \$g_{m1}=4.4721\mathrm{mA/V}\$, \$g_{m2}=40\mathrm{mA/V}\$, \$r_{p_i}=2.5\mathrm{kohm}\$, \$r_e=23.97\mathrm{kohm}\$.

I've looked all over the internet and can't find any examples of a MOSFET cascaded with a BJT. Every example out there is either two MOSFETs or two BJTs. Please help.

[image: Original amplifier circuit]

Comment: Start by drawing the small signal models

Comment: Why do you think that the MOSFET will have some effect on Rout? For the circuit, you have shown the output resistance is Rout = ro2

Comment: I originally thought the Rout for the circuit was ro2. But the previous question was worth 5 points and asked me to find the individual Rin and Rout for each transistor. And then the next question was worth 8 points and asked me to find the overall Rin and Rout for the amplifier. I thought it was weird for a trick question asking the same thing as the previous question to be worth more points.

Comment: I was given that behemoth of an amplifier circuit with the given parameters that Iref, I1, and I2 all equal 1mA. Vdd is +12V. And I was given the threshold voltages of each transistor as well as their areas, kn, and channel length modulation factor.

Comment: @StankNasty Well for this new circuit Rout is ro2||ro3 so you need to know the Early voltage value for Q2 (BJT's) and lambda (channel length modulation factor lambda \$\lambda\$) for Q3 MOSFET.